# Simplification and circles pointing to axis help of multiple coloured yaxis pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I have generated the below plot how I want.

### Can this be simplified?

However I found it very convoluted to colour the y axis, labels and tick labels, whilst keeping the x axis black.
Setting the colour style of the axis seems particularly bad.

```
y axis line style = {mycolor2},
y axis line style = {mycolor2},
y tick label style= {mycolor2},
y tick style= {mycolor2},
ylabel style = {mycolor2},
```

Is there a simpler way that I can do this?

[image: Multi Y axis plot[1]]

### How to do circles around lines

I would also like to put circles around each line pointing to the axis which it is linked to. How is best to do that?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}
\begin{document}
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=(\hsize/2),
height=(\hsize/2),
at={(0.2in,0.444in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.5,
xlabel near ticks,
xlabel={Density $\lambda$},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.00035,
ylabel near ticks,
ylabel={Rate, ($s^{-1}$)},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
y axis line style = {mycolor1},
y axis line style = {mycolor1},
y tick label style= {mycolor1},
y tick style= {mycolor1},
ylabel style = {mycolor1},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor1}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1e-05   0.000349984346613178\\
0.0250095   0.000294763280950208\\
0.100008    0.000223262905327838\\
0.1750065   0.000189761632377871\\
0.250005    0.000168814588345592\\
0.3250035   0.000153988764794569\\
0.400002    0.000142726344312675\\
0.4750005   0.000133766561301556\\
0.5 0.000131160050335831\\
};\label{rate_plot}
\addlegendentry{Rate}

\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[%
width=(\hsize/2),
height=(\hsize/2),
at={(0.2in,0.444in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.5,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.00035,
ylabel near ticks,
ylabel={Rate 2, ($s^{-1}$)},
hide x axis,
axis y line*= right,
y axis line style = {mycolor2},
y axis line style = {mycolor2},
y tick label style= {mycolor2},
y tick style= {mycolor2},
ylabel style = {mycolor2},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=black, text=black}
]
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=rate_plot}\addlegendentry{Rate}
\addplot [color=mycolor2, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor2}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1e-05   0.00016332275313237\\
0.0250095   0.000115848009059579\\
0.100008    6.64661750163849e-05\\
0.1750065   4.80196831721179e-05\\
0.250005    3.80067958197952e-05\\
0.3250035   3.16272652493933e-05\\
0.400002    2.71728300947399e-05\\
0.4750005   2.38707996203775e-05\\
0.5 2.29503949117285e-05\\
};
\addlegendentry{Rate 2}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

### Posts used already

[Can I draw figure 3 y axis using pgfplot?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62291/can-i-draw-figure-3-y-axis-using-pgfplot)

[Change legend color in multiple y-axis plot in pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223312/change-legend-color-in-multiple-y-axis-plot-in-pgfplots)

[pgfplots: two y-axis with three plots and one legend](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198997/pgfplots-two-y-axis-with-three-plots-and-one-legend)

Comment: The color of the line matches the color of the plot so why the circles again?? Overkill!!

Comment: The circles is because it has to be suitably clear for greyscale reproduction

Answer (score 1):

You could define a style for that,

```
\pgfplotsset{yaxis stuff style/.style={y axis line style = {#1},
y tick label style= {#1},
y tick style= {#1},
ylabel style = {#1},
}}
```

and use it in the two axes.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\pgfplotsset{yaxis stuff style/.style={y axis line style = {#1},
y tick label style= {#1},
y tick style= {#1},
ylabel style = {#1},
}}
\begin{document}
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=(\hsize/2),
height=(\hsize/2),
at={(0.2in,0.444in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.5,
xlabel near ticks,
xlabel={Density $\lambda$},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.00035,
ylabel near ticks,
ylabel={Rate, ($s^{-1}$)},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
yaxis stuff style = {mycolor1},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor1}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1e-05   0.000349984346613178\\
0.0250095   0.000294763280950208\\
0.100008    0.000223262905327838\\
0.1750065   0.000189761632377871\\
0.250005    0.000168814588345592\\
0.3250035   0.000153988764794569\\
0.400002    0.000142726344312675\\
0.4750005   0.000133766561301556\\
0.5 0.000131160050335831\\
};\label{rate_plot}
\addlegendentry{Rate}

\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[%
width=(\hsize/2),
height=(\hsize/2),
at={(0.2in,0.444in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.5,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.00035,
ylabel near ticks,
ylabel={Rate 2, ($s^{-1}$)},
hide x axis,
axis y line*= right,
yaxis stuff style = {mycolor2},
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=black, text=black}
]
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=rate_plot}\addlegendentry{Rate}
\addplot [color=mycolor2, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor2}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1e-05   0.00016332275313237\\
0.0250095   0.000115848009059579\\
0.100008    6.64661750163849e-05\\
0.1750065   4.80196831721179e-05\\
0.250005    3.80067958197952e-05\\
0.3250035   3.16272652493933e-05\\
0.400002    2.71728300947399e-05\\
0.4750005   2.38707996203775e-05\\
0.5 2.29503949117285e-05\\
};
\addlegendentry{Rate 2}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

In principle you could only add `\color{mycolor1}` and `\color{mycolor2}` before the respective axis.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
% This file was created by matlab2tikz.
\definecolor{mycolor1}{rgb}{0.00000,0.44700,0.74100}%
\definecolor{mycolor2}{rgb}{0.85000,0.32500,0.09800}%
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\color{mycolor1}
\begin{axis}[%
width=(\hsize/2),
height=(\hsize/2),
at={(0.2in,0.444in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.5,
xlabel near ticks,
xlabel={Density $\lambda$},
ymin=0,
ymax=0.00035,
ylabel near ticks,
ylabel={Rate, ($s^{-1}$)},
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=white!15!black}
]
\addplot [color=mycolor1, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor1}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1e-05   0.000349984346613178\\
0.0250095   0.000294763280950208\\
0.100008    0.000223262905327838\\
0.1750065   0.000189761632377871\\
0.250005    0.000168814588345592\\
0.3250035   0.000153988764794569\\
0.400002    0.000142726344312675\\
0.4750005   0.000133766561301556\\
0.5 0.000131160050335831\\
};\label{rate_plot}
\addlegendentry{Rate}

\end{axis}
\color{mycolor2}
\begin{axis}[%
width=(\hsize/2),
height=(\hsize/2),
at={(0.2in,0.444in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=0.5,
ymin=0,
ymax=0.00035,
ylabel near ticks,
ylabel={Rate 2, ($s^{-1}$)},
hide x axis,
axis y line*= right,
xmajorgrids,
ymajorgrids,
legend style={legend cell align=left, align=left, draw=black, text=black}
]
\addlegendimage{/pgfplots/refstyle=rate_plot}\addlegendentry{Rate}
\addplot [color=mycolor2, mark=o, mark options={solid, mycolor2}]
  table[row sep=crcr]{%
1e-05   0.00016332275313237\\
0.0250095   0.000115848009059579\\
0.100008    6.64661750163849e-05\\
0.1750065   4.80196831721179e-05\\
0.250005    3.80067958197952e-05\\
0.3250035   3.16272652493933e-05\\
0.400002    2.71728300947399e-05\\
0.4750005   2.38707996203775e-05\\
0.5 2.29503949117285e-05\\
};
\addlegendentry{Rate 2}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%

\end{document}
```

However, I do not recommend that.